# funcall in C++ : declaring functions that take functions as parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, function-object

There are a lot of examples on the web of using STL to pass in functions or function objects as parameters, for example in std::count .

How do I write my own functions that take such arguments?

As a simple example, say my class is:

```
struct Foo{
 int val=0;
 int methodinc()const{return val+1};
 }
```

I would like to define a function funcall like:

```
int funcall (foo arg, function f) 
  {return f(arg); }
```

where the declaration “function” is what I am not sure of, among other things. The term “funcall” comes from Lisp, where `(funcall f a b c)` just applies `f` to the arguments a b c.

Then something like this should work:

```
Foo ff;

funcall(ff,Foo::methodinc); // should return 1
funcall(ff, [](Foo x) {return x.val+1;}) // should return 1
```

What are simple ways to accomplish this?

I am writing these as debugging helpers, the “funcall” would be used as part of the implementation of my own like my own data structure’s analogs of count, remove-if, transform and other like STL functions that take function arguments. But I do not want to write complicated template expressions to define my code.

---

The initial answers to this question suggest that the whole notion of declaring and using function arguments is a bit obscure, at least to me. Perhaps before addressing funcall, an even easier task might be just to pass a functional argument to another function, not use it. For example, in C++, to count a vector v I have to write

```
std::count(v.begin, v.end(), [](int j){return j>3})
```

How can one write a count that always counts the whole vector, so that:

```
 mycount(v,[](int j){return j>3})
```

is the same as above? And could this "mycount" work for member function pointers instead of lambdas?

This question is basically the same as the "funcall" question but without the requirement actually to call the function object that is passed.

Comment: Do you need a function that takes an arbitrary amount of arguments? That's possible too, with C++11. `funcall(f, a, b, c)` etc.

Comment: OK, I added these fixes, thanks for the correction. No, I do not need variable arg #s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically a function *template* suits this sort of need for flexibility best:

```
template <typename F, typename T>
auto funcall(T && t, F f) -> decltype(f(std::forward<T>(t))
{
    return f(std::forward<T>(t));
}
```

Instead of the trailing return type and `decltype` you can also use the `result_of` trait:

```
template <typename F, typename T>
typename std::result_of<F(T&&)>::type funcall(T && t, F f)
{
    return f(std::forward<T>(t));
}
```

Or, in C++14, you can just say `decltype(auto) funcall(T && t, F f)` with no trailing return type, and it'll be deduced automatically.

The main reason for making `F` a deduced template argument rather than a fixed type (such as `std::function<R(T)>` is to allow you to call `funcall` directly with lambdas and `bind`/`mem_fn` expressions, which have unknowable types. Passing those directly allows efficient inlining opportunities, whereas creating of an `std::function` object is rather expensive by comparison.

Comment: Is there an even simpler way, let's say if I know the arguments of funcall are always an argument of type Foo and another "function" that takes a "Foo" and returns an "int"? I am not worried about efficiency, just writing short, simple, easy to understand code.

Comment: Why take `F` by value?  @kdog do you care about low level performance in this case?

Comment: @Yakk: Meh. Move semantics, copy elision, you name it. I could change it to a reference, I suppose.

Comment: No I do not care about performance here. By the way, how would I write a wrapper for say std::count() so that mycount(vec,f) would be the same as mycount(vec.begin(),vec.end(),f)  for a lambda f ?

Comment: @kdog: `template <typename C, typename F> void mycount(C && c, F f) { mycount(c.begin(), c.end(), f); }`?!

Comment: Ah that looks very helpful...but do you mean "count" not "mycount" in the second use of the term, and also mycount returns int (or size_t) not void, right?

Comment: You know what I do then Kerrek if this is reasonable - I might just give up on funcall entirely and just convert my datastructures on the fly to a vec, and then pass the function in. That way I don't have to worry about std::forward and multiple && (which I assume I can ignore, right, and not use? ) .

Comment: @kdog please try to keep questions on topic.  If you have a completely different problem (like mycount) first search the net for an answer, try some stuff yourself, and failing that ask a new stack overflow question.

Comment: You're right Yakk. But the motivation was the same: to find the simplest possible way to take a function-like value as a parameter. So it is not really all that different a problem. The mycount question I was hoping would be an easier version of the funcall question. I haven't found anything useful on the web addressing the issue of writing functions that take function arguments. Virtually every article focuses only on using lambdas to invoke STL functions, and many of the remainder predate C++11. But I will edit the original post to clarify.

Comment: @kdog: It might be better to ask a new, separate question. It's very difficult to maintain a useful question-answer system if the question keeps moving. There's nothing wrong with the question as asked.

Comment: You're right, the question. But hold on, one last question/comment. Could we implement funcall, without arcane templating, just by creating a one element vector, and then passing that vector and the input function to std::transform, and then returning the first element of the vector? (Now sure if this would work for member functions instead of lambdas though). Something like ...vector<Foo> v{arg}; return transform(v.begin(),v.end(),f))[0]

Answer (score 1):

C++ is an extraordinarily powerful and complex language. In it you can do anything you can do in Lisp, including implementing Lisp yourself. The problem is that to get there you will have to learn rather a lot about the language and what it can do. Using functions as objects is unfortunately one of the most complicated parts of C++.

There are multiple ways to solve your problem. The @Kerrek answer is an excellent one, but clearly beyond what you're ready for. The code provided in your edit is for a lambda, which will not necessarily make things simpler.

At its heart, function objects in C++ are just pointers. They look like this.

```
typedef int (*func)(int a, char b);

int f(int aa, char bb) {
  return aa + bb;
}

int main(void) {
  func fv = f;
  int ret = fv(10, ' ');
  printf ("ret=%d", ret);
  return 0;
}
```

Here func is a type representing a function call, f is the actual function and fv is a functional call variable.

From this structure all else is built. With templates the compiler does the type matching and with lambdas you avoid having to think up nmes. Underneath it all, C/C++ functions are just pointers.

So the answer is that you can write your own functions that take functions as arguments when you know that those arguments are simply pointers to functions of a suitable type, declared as shown above.

Comment: This is a good answer actually. Actually I have written methods that take member functions as arguments, and I was hoping easily to extend these to lambdas, but never quite understood how.

Comment: There should be a good reference to "basic functional programming in C++". One that lies between the cookbook approaches "here is how you call transform" in all the books and the references I have seen on the one hand, and the cryptic language of the standard on the other. Especially since lambdas in theory should make this style of programming more popular.

Comment: Good enough for an upvote maybe? The problem with C++ is that it is the ultimate leaky abstraction. You cannot effectively work at the highest levels of abstraction until you have mastered the levels below. That turns out to be quite limiting.